# VAPOR Server with Twitter API

Tags: swift, twitter, vpn, vapor

I'm trying to explore twitter API from VAPOR server. And I'm getting the following error:

```
[ INFO ] GET /hello [request-id: F00915F3-0812-429A-B012-BEDCAE1DD543]
[ WARNING ] read(descriptor:pointer:size:): Connection reset by peer (errno: 54) [request-id: F00915F3-0812-429A-B012-BEDCAE1DD543]
```

The problem is that I'm in Russia and you can get Twitter only through VPN. And it works just fine:

```
[ INFO ] GET /hello [request-id: 18EFDB9C-98CE-45F2-90E6-ABDC34983051]
Response(data: App.DataClass(id: "44196397", name: "Elon Musk", username: "elonmusk"))
```

GET request with 'Reqbin' or 'Postman' is okay. But when I'm deploying this project on 'render.com' or 'railway.com' which servers are outside the firewall, US and Germany, the problem remains the same.
So maybe something wrong with API? Or maybe I need some request tweaking.

I'm pretty sure this is not VAPOR problem, because the same error arises from XCode Project or Playground.

P.S. request from Windows Powershell the same situation, works with VPN. Maybe anyone has an idea in which direction to dig))

```
import Vapor
 
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
    app.get { req async in
        "It works!"
    }
 
    app.get("hello") { req -> EventLoopFuture<Response> in
        try getUser(request: req)
    }
    
    func getUser(request: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeaders([("Authorization", "Bearer \(Environment.get("BEARER_TOKEN")!)")])
        let uri: URI = URI(string: "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/elonmusk")
        
        return request.client.get(uri, headers: headers).flatMapThrowing { response in
            guard response.status == .ok else { throw Abort(.unauthorized) }
            guard let buffer = response.body else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
            guard let data = String(buffer: buffer).data(using: .utf8) else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
            
            do {
                let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                print(data)
                return data
            } catch {
                throw Abort(.badRequest)
            }
        }
    }
}
// Response Model
struct Response: Content, Codable {
    let data: DataClass
}
 
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id, name, username: String
}
```

Comment: Two days I was banging my head, then I tried to create brand new vapor project and deploy it. And it worked. I don't know why, but old still even they are equal and deployed on the same server, maybe missed something. But good thing to proxy vapor with nginx, and Vapor does have a good documentation.